# String manipulation in R: How to print with cat(...,sep=" ") but omit the last space?

Tags: r, string, printing, cat

I'm using R to print a MPLUS command. I have to specify covariances among lots of variables. Therefore, I have to create all subsets of a set. In MPLUS it has to be specified like this (if we consider a list of 4 variables female, age, edu migrant):

```
female WITH age edu migrant;
age WITH edu migrant;
edu WITH migrant;
```

which stands for all subsets of size 2 of the set of  4 variables (female WITH age; female WITH edu; female WITH migrant; age WITH edu; age WITH migrant; edu WITH migrant;).

In order to get an output that I can directly copy into MPLUS, I use the command cat(). Unfortunately, I can't get the output shown above but only this output (notice the semicolon):

```
female WITH age edu migrant ;
age WITH edu migrant ;
edu WITH migrant ;
```

I played around a lot with paste, cat and print. But either I get an output with one space before the semicolon at the end of the line (like directly above), or I get this:

```
female WITH ageedumigrant;
age WITH edumigrant;
edu WITH migrant;
```

So my question basically is: How can I omit the last space in the cat(...,sep=" ") command?

My small function looks like this:

```
library(stringr)
vars_b <- "female age edu migrant"

covstructure <- function(x, cov = TRUE, var = TRUE, width = 80) {

  # decode variable list into a vector, e.g. x[1] = "female" #
  x <- gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x, perl=TRUE)
  x <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))

  # covariance structure (the part of interest here) #
  if(cov==TRUE) {

    # all combinations #
    result <- combn(x,2)

    # get subsets into the MPLUS format: #
    # female WITH age edu migrant; #
    # age WITH edu migrant; #
    # edu WITH migrant; #

    for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {

      # indices of the combinations that include the i-th variable #
      ind <- which(result==x[i])

      # print variable WITH its combinations #
      # here is my problem: #
      cat(result[which.min(ind)], "WITH", result[ind+1], ";", fill=width)

      # create new combinations without the combinations of preceding variables, i.e. 1 to i #
      if(i < length(x)-1) { result <- combn(x[-c(1:i)],2) }
    }
  }

  # variance structure (not of interest) #
  if(var==TRUE) {
    cat(x, "", sep="; ", fill=width)
  }
}

covstructure(vars_b, cov=TRUE, var=FALSE)
```

I hope I could lay out the problem (which is entirely about R string manipulation) carefully enough and thank you very much in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a good way to do this -

```
x <- c("female", "WITH", "age", "edu", "migrant")
y<-do.call(paste, c(as.list(x), sep=" "))
k<-paste(y,";",sep="")
```

Now the String k will be as your desired string -

```
[1] "female WITH age edu migrant;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Will the following code work for you?

```
x <- c("female", "WITH", "age", "edu", "migrant")
cat(cat(x), ";", sep="")
```